# What's the syntax to import an image from a distant Folder?

Tags: javascript, import, filesystems

```
src
+ admin
++ price
+++ Price.js
+ img
++ cu.svg
```

Hi, I need to import `cu` to component “Price” but none of these work, and I get a "can't resolve" message:

```
import cu from '../img/cu.svg';
import cu from '.../img/cu.svg';
```

Is there a way to solve this? I couldn't find any answer that can do it.

Thanks!

Comment: The `src` folder is up two levels, so you need `../../` to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import statement is wrong, try something like this;

`import cu from '../../img/cu.svg';`

I'm assuming that admin and img both are on same level, and Price.js is inside admin/price.